# How to convert RGB images to grayscale in matlab without using rgb2gray

Tags: matlab

I'm currently using code:

```
i = imread('/usr/share/icons/matlab.png');
for k=1:1:m
    for l=1:1:n
        %a(k,l)=m*n;
        a(k,l) = (.299*i(k,l,1))+(.587*i(k,l,2))+(.114*i(k,l,3));
    end
end
imshow(a);
```

It shows only a white screen. Also the newly generated dimensions are n x m x 3 whereas it should be only m x n x 1.

If I use mat2gray it display the image like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the image is a PNG, [`imread()` is returning an *integer* image](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imread.html?searchHighlight=imread#f25-713750), with intensity values in the range `[0 255]` or equivalent, depending on the original bit depth. The conversion formula makes `a` a *double* image, which is expected to have intensities in the range `[0 1]`. Since all the pixel values in `a` are probably much greater than 1, they get clipped to 1 (white) by `imshow()`.

The best option is to [explicitly convert the image format](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/im2double.html) before you start - this will take care of scaling things correctly:

```
i = imread('/usr/share/icons/matlab.png');
i = im2double(i);
a = .299*i(:,:,1) + .587*i(:,:,2) + .114*i(:,:,3);  % no need for loops
imshow(a);
```

Comment: `im2double` could be replaced with `double(i)./double(intmax(class(i)))`, assuming the image processing toolbox is not available

Comment: It seems im2double is not required if I use you're equation.

Comment: @user3263192 Yes, if you don't preallocate `a` it will create an integer greyscale image at the original bit depth, in which case rescaling isn't needed. Watch out for rounding and overflow if you're working with integers though - doubles may be preferable for more complex processing algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

```
input=imread('test.jpg');
subplot(1,2,1), imshow(input), title('RGB Scale image');
[x,y,~] = size(input);

for i = 1:1:x
   for j = 1:1:y
      output(i,j) = 0.40*input(i,j,1) + 0.50*input(i,j,2) + 0.30*input(i,j,3);
   end
end

subplot(1,2,2), imshow(output), title('Gray Scale  image');
```